# Breaking up PascalCase in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a series of character strings using PascalCase.

```
"BobDylan"
"MikhailGorbachev" 
"HelpfulStackOverflowPeople"
```

I want a function in R that will put spaces between each word. I have achieved this with a perl like regular expression and the `gsub( )` function. Essentially, I am putting a space before every capital letter that is not the first letter of the string.

```
gsub("(?!^)(?=[A-Z])", " ","BobDylan",perl=TRUE)
[1] "Bob Dylan"
```

However, some of the words in my list may have capitalized abbreviations in them that I do not want to have separated by spaces.

```
"BobDylanUSA"
"MikhailGorbachevUSSR" 
"HelpfulStackOverflowPeople"
```

Applying the same syntax from before will create spaces between every capital letter.

```
gsub("(?!^)(?=[A-Z])", " ","MikhailGorbachevUSSR",perl=TRUE)
[1] "Mikhail Gorbachev U S S R"
```

However, I would like for the abbreviations to stay the same. The desired output would look like the following.

```
[1] "Bob Dylan USA"
[1] "Mikhail Gorbachev USSR"
[1] "Helpful Stack Overflow People"
```

What else do I need to do in my `gsub( )` expression? Alternatively, is there a better way to approach this problem entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- c("BobDylanUSA",
       "MikhailGorbachevUSSR",
       "HelpfulStackOverflowPeople")

gsub('[a-z]\\K(?=[A-Z])', ' ', x, perl = TRUE)

# [1] "Bob Dylan USA"                 "Mikhail Gorbachev USSR"       
# [3] "Helpful Stack Overflow People"
```

Or

```
gsub('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', ' ', x, perl = TRUE)

# [1] "Bob Dylan USA"                 "Mikhail Gorbachev USSR"       
# [3] "Helpful Stack Overflow People"
```

Or this guy which will also split single letter words like I or A

```
x <- c("BobDylanUSA",
       "MikhailGorbachevUSSR",
       "HelpfulStackOverflowPeople",
       "IAmATallDrinkOfWater")

gsub('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])', ' ', x, perl = TRUE)

# [1] "Bob Dylan USA"                 "Mikhail Gorbachev USSR"       
# [3] "Helpful Stack Overflow People" "I Am A Tall Drink Of Water"
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how it could be done using the default method of regex?

Comment: @AdamBirenbaum what do you mean by default, without `perl=TRUE`?

Comment: I am not sure the single word regex is possible at all. Even your lookaround-based one [fails with *MailSentToUSAADayAgo*](https://regex101.com/r/bT7oL8/2) (when one letter word comes after the abbrev).

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your own regex just a bit: convert the lookahead into a capturing group and add the `+` quantifier after the `[A-Z]` character class to make it match 1+ characters:

```
> v <- c("BobDylan","MikhailGorbachev","HelpfulStackOverflowPeople","BobDylanUSA","MikhailGorbachevUSSR","HelpfulStackOverflowPeople")
> gsub("(?<!^|\\s)([A-Z]+)", " \\1", v, perl=T)
[1] "Bob Dylan"                     "Mikhail Gorbachev"            
[3] "Helpful Stack Overflow People" "Bob Dylan USA"                
[5] "Mikhail Gorbachev USSR"        "Helpful Stack Overflow People"
```

It is still a PCRE regex since you do not want to add a space at the beginning of the string (which is prevented with a lookbehind `(?<!^)` here, and only if there is no whitespace before the uppercase letters.

**See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW1mH3/1)**

**NON-PCRE ALTERNATIVE**

If you want to try a *TRE* (non-PCRE) regex use

```
> gsub("(\\S)([A-Z]+)", "\\1 \\2", v)
[1] "Bob Dylan"                     "Mikhail Gorbachev"            
[3] "Helpful Stack Overflow People" "Bob Dylan USA"                
[5] "Mikhail Gorbachev USSR"        "Helpful Stack Overflow People"
```

Here is **[another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW1mH3/2)**.

Here, the pattern matches and captures any one non-whitespace character with `(\\S)` followed with 1+ uppercase ASCII letters captured into Group 2 (see `([A-Z]+)`) and then we use `\\1` and `\\2` [numbered backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in the replacement pattern to add a space between those captured subvalues.

**My try at splitting out the one-word capital letters**

Since the one-letter words can be matched just once, we need to be able to match the locations before and after them, which requires the use of *lookarounds* since only lookarounds allow "overlapping" matches by performing the so-called zero-width assertion checks on the text before (lookbehinds) and after (lookaheads) the current position. Thus, **only a PCRE regex can handle that**.

That said, either solution will yield the same result:

```
(?|([a-z])(?=[A-Z])|([A-Z]+)(?=[A-Z][a-z]))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vW0xU0/1).

*The issue will remain with one-word letters **after capitalized abbreviations** (see `Mail Sent To USAA Day Ago`).* You'd need some dictionary check then.

```
> v <- c("BobDylan","MikhailGorbachev","BobDylanUSA","MikhailGorbachevUSSR","HelpfulStackOverflowPeople","IAmATallDrinkOfWater","MailSentToUSAADayAgo")
> gsub("(?|([a-z])(?=[A-Z])|([A-Z]+)(?=[A-Z][a-z]))", "\\1 ", v, perl=T)
[1] "Bob Dylan"                     "Mikhail Gorbachev"            
[3] "Bob Dylan USA"                 "Mikhail Gorbachev USSR"       
[5] "Helpful Stack Overflow People" "I Am A Tall Drink Of Water"   
[7] "Mail Sent To USAA Day Ago"
```

The pattern will match and capture into Group 1 both the capture groups inside the pattern because of the [*branch reset*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) (`(?|...|...)`). The captured text is inserted back via a backreference, and then a space is added.

- `([a-z])(?=[A-Z])` - after a lowercase letter that is followed with an uppercase one
- `([A-Z]+)(?=[A-Z][a-z])` - after 1+ uppercase letters that are followed with 1 uppercase and then 1 lowercase letter.

Comment: @Adam, please check my second suggestion.

Comment: can you extend it to work for single letter words? Mine seems overly complicated

Comment: @rawr: I added one, but it is no better, I consider it impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I just developed the snakecase package for such purposes and would like to promote a bit;-) Hope this helps!

```
install.packages("snakecase")
library(snakecase)

string <- c("BobDylanUSA",
            "MikhailGorbachevUSSR",
            "HelpfulStackOverflowPeople",
            "IAmATallDrinkOfWater")

to_any_case(string, case = "parsed", sep_out = " ")
#> [1] "Bob Dylan USA"                 "Mikhail Gorbachev USSR"       
#> [3] "Helpful Stack Overflow People" "I Am A Tall Drink Of Water"
```

https://github.com/Tazinho/snakecase